# How to disable/remove Terminal script?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion

A while ago I wrote a Terminal script that executes `cd Desktop` every time I start Terminal.

With the release of Lion, this is no longer necessary as Terminal remembers where I last left off. I can't figure out how to disable/delete the script because I can't find it. There are also no options in the Terminal preferences that can help me. How do I disable or delete this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably controlled by one of the following files in your home directory, which you can edit/delete to remove this behavior:

- `.bashrc`
- `.bash_profile`
- `.profile`